# Can I stop other PHP processes and continue with a new one?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a plugin for WordPress that needs to create it's own unique style of pages.

The way the process was explained to me by someone else who did something similar was that when the first hook was ran, they did something like an exit() and then continued with their own code. That enabled them to show their own HTML on a page completely separate from the main theme and all that.

However, I've been unsuccessful at my attempts.

Here's my (basic) code for this.

```
function wps_show_page() {
    if ($_GET['scratch'] == 1) {
        exit();

        //This is where I need to echo out a bunch of HTML
    }
}
```

When I run this, nothing shows up on the page.

Which, I guess makes sense since I think exit() just shuts everything down for that thread.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
exit( '<p>some HTML</p>' );
?>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Please please please provide explanation, too, instead of just throwing random code.

Comment: @Wahyu While this may be completely lacking in explanation, it definitely answers the question.